# Where do I give feedback about the Lubuntu website?

Tags: lubuntu

I tried to download new Lubuntu by torrent. Installed and... Well on http://lubuntu.net/ there is wrong link to torrent. Gives 14.10 but should 15.04.

I tried to find another way to contact but, lubuntu contact redirecting to page from ubuntu wiki, where is no possibility to give feedback without creating new accounts.

Where can I find simply contact form where I will be able to write one line without reading tons of text, searching proper category, creating accounts or subscribing to mailing list? Because I'm angry and I would like to save others people problems with downloading wrong version.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have to be on the mailing list to send them an email but I found this email here:  lubuntu-qa@lists.launchpad.net  you can also  lubuntu-users@lists.ubuntu.com. You can sign up for the users list here if you would like to receive followups and future posts https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/lubuntu-users

Comment: I found the link you are looking for and yes, the link on the main page directs you to the 14.10 version for i386 but if you click on  the "downloads" page you will get the correct one http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.04/release/lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent

Comment: I already have installed lubuntu from full iso :) there ware no problem to find other place with proper link. I lose some time and I just wos confused where can I report wrong url on main page. Every is fine, lubuntu is installed. I just reply on comments to don't leave it without answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have to be on the mailing list to send them an email but I found this email here:

lubuntu-qa@lists.launchpad.net

you can also

lubuntu-users@lists.ubuntu.com

You can sign up for the users list here if you would like to receive followups and future posts https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/lubuntu-users

---

The proper download link should be this instead:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.04/release/lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent

---

Also, you can upgrade to 15.04 by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04-from-ubuntu-13-10-or-12-04/

Comment: Yes upgrade is fine, but I need minimal and clean installation: I many times upgraded ubuntu version and well, many times just install new version works better. I didn't want to have problems on just installed machine.

Comment: @senfen have you tried the mini.iso?; it's 35-40MB vs  the usual 650-700MB. It is a net install iso and does not have the option to "try Lubuntu". You also have more option to only install a bare minimum system see here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall and download the 32 bit version here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso or the 64 bit version here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso I never mess with full iso images anymore.

Comment: Yes, minimal iso is great. But it also download many files during installation. I installed lubuntu with minimal on my second PC. But these one haven't internet access so I haven't choice and had download full image ;)

Comment: @senfen I found the link you were looking for: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.04/release/lubuntu-15.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent I found it here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Before writing an "angry" email, I would encourage you to remember the Ubuntu Code of Conduct, which you can review here: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/conduct Please remember that Ubuntu's flavors like Lubuntu are primarily managed by volunteers.

The Lubuntu wiki page that you found included a big link that said "Contact Us" - that page includes a number of ways to get in touch with the Lubuntu team: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/ContactUs

Lubuntu 15.04 release images are available here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/vivid/release/

And, for the future, you can always find images for Ubuntu releases by following the links at http://releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: "big link that said "Contact Us"". Yes, I wrote about it. There are many ways and no one simple contact form. You can subscribe to mailing list, you can create account on ubuntu forum, you can create facebook account and visit theirs fanpage, you can ask for help and so on. But there is no way to simple fill form about error on website, or even email for common problems. I found 15.04 release, but the problem was that i waste 4 hours of life because i installed wrong version.

Comment: The IRC chat does not require registration - and feedback provided there will be seen by members of the team eventually, if no one is in chat at that time. If you think having a web feedback form would be valuable, feel free to leave that in the IRC chat, or better yet, as a suggestion on the mailing list or in the forums so the community can discuss it. The problem I see with a form to fill out is - where does it go? Like I said, the team is all volunteer, so assigning one person to receive all feedback could be a huge burden. This website (AU) crowd-sources these questions effectively.

Comment: I was considering IRC but I never met with reporting bugs on chat especially when it is described as support :) I send email yesterday about bug on website to email address from chosen answer. I received back email about verification because of unsubscribed user, but I guess that someone will read this finally.